# How do I iterate through specific rows & columns in Python?

Tags: python

I am a beginner, and this is for my Intro to Python class. I have been trying to figure out how to pull North Carolina's data for 2012-13 in this program. After that, it will need to be charted using matplotlib, but that is for another time.

I've managed to create a list & dictionary with appropriately assigned keys, values. I'm stuck on trying to pull this information in together, and I hope you guys can help.

This is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib as plt
import csv

table = []

with open('influenza.csv') as file:
    flu_data = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
    next(flu_data) # will skip headers - see Bib 1
    for row in flu_data:
        break
    #print(table)

    for line in flu_data:
        row = {}
        row["state"] = line[0]
        row["url"] = line[1]
        row["website"] = line[2]
        row["activity level"] = line[3]
        row["activity level label"] = line[4]
        row["weekend"] = line[5]
        row["week"] = line[6]
        row["season"] = line[7]
        table.append(row) 
                      
for row in range(len(table)):              
    for col in range(len(table[row])):      
        if table[row["state"]][col["state"]] == "North Carolina" and table[row["season"]]    [col["season"]] == "2012-13":            
             print(table)
```

I was hoping that this would pull the information that I need, but it is giving this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. I apologize if this is bad question, but I am new and haven't really seen something like this answered before. I know that Pandas exists and it would most likely be easier to do something like this through that library, but we haven't covered that and I'm not sure that is what my professor is looking for. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: The last line in the output before the error message should tell you which line number in your code has the error. Can you please edit this question to add in the full error message and add in a `#` comment at the end of the line indicating which line that is in your code sample here?

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the elements of the list rather than the indexes. Your code will be much cleaner this way.

There's also no need for a nested loop. Since each element in the table is a dict, you can just check the appropriate properties on each row.

```
for row in table:
    if row['state'] == 'North Carolina' and row['season'] == '2012-13':
        print(row)
```

Note that [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) can parse the header row for you and create a `dict` from each subsequent row based on the names of the columns. There is no need rewrite that logic manually.

With this, most of your code can be simplified to the following line (assuming the header row has the same names as you are using in the code):

```py
table = [*csv.DictReader(file)]
```